# Airflow Exception not being thrown when encountering None/Falsy values

Tags: airflow

I am trying to pass data between a PythonOperator, `_etl_lasic` to another PythonOperator, `_download_s3_data`, which works fine but I want to throw an exception when the value passed is `None` which should mark the task as a failure.

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowFailException


def _etl_lasic(**context):
    path_s3 = None
    context["task_instance"].xcom_push(
        key="path_s3",
        value=path_s3,
    )


def _download_s3_data(templates_dict, **context):
    path_s3 = templates_dict["path_s3"]
    if not path_s3:
        raise AirflowFailException("Path to S3 was not passed!")
    else:
        print(f"Path to S3: {path_s3}")


with DAG(
    dag_id="02_lasic_retraining_without_etl",
    start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(3),
    schedule_interval="@once",
) as dag:

    etl_lasic = PythonOperator(
        task_id="etl_lasic",
        python_callable=_etl_lasic,
    )

    download_s3_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id="download_s3_data",
        python_callable=_download_s3_data,
        templates_dict={
            "path_s3": "{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='etl_lasic',key='path_s3')}}"
        },
    )

    etl_lasic >> download_s3_data
```

Logs:

```
[2021-08-17 04:04:41,128] {logging_mixin.py:103} INFO - Path to S3: None
[2021-08-17 04:04:41,128] {python.py:118} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
[2021-08-17 04:04:41,143] {taskinstance.py:1135} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=02_lasic_retraining_without_etl, task_id=download_s3_data, execution_date=20210817T040439, start_date=20210817T040440, end_date=20210817T040441
[2021-08-17 04:04:41,189] {taskinstance.py:1195} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
[2021-08-17 04:04:41,212] {local_task_job.py:118} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja-templated values are rendered as strings by default.  In your case, even though you push an XCom value of `None`, when the value is pulled via `"{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='etl_lasic',key='path_s3')}}"` the value is *actually* rendered as "None" which doesn't throw an exception based on the current logic.

There are two options that will solve this:

1. Instead of setting `path_s3` to `None` in the "_etl_lasic" function, set it to an empty string.
2. If you are using Airflow 2.1+, there is a parameter, `render_template_as_native_obj`, that can be set at the DAG level which will render Jinja-templated values as native Python types (list, dict, etc.). Setting that parameter to `True` will do the trick without changing how `path_s3` is set in the function.  A conceptual example is documented [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects).

Comment: Thanks yeah I am using Airflow 2.1+ and that works. Since it is a string I could also use `ast.literal_eval(path_s3)` to convert the string to its literal value as well.